# What is the probability that TEAM A will win in both of the following scenarios?

Tags: probability, statistics

Two teams are in the same league and just finished a season. Assume both teams had played the exact same schedule. TEAM A had a winrate of 90% and TEAM B had a winrate of 70%. If both teams then meet each other head to head during a tournament, with your only knowledge of the two teams being their winrate, what are the odds of TEAM A winning in a Best of One match, and what are the odds of TEAM A winning in a Best of Three match.

I know logic tells us that due to TEAM A having the better record competing against the same opponents they should have a higher probability of winning. Additionally, I believe the probability of TEAM A winning is higher in a best of 3 than in a best of 1. My understanding of probability is that the larger the sample size of games, the more likely the results will reflect what the probability suggested, where in a smaller sample size, it is easier for an upset. My curiosity is at what rate do the odds of an upset get smaller between a BO1 and a BO3.

The probability of me being all over the place and not making any sense is high, so ask questions for clarification. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Draw a probability tree.

Comment: To clarify:  I expect you want to make the simplifying assumption that every game between any two teams is an independent toss of a (weighted) coin.  That is, you want to disregard "hot streaks" or "cold spells" and so on.  Even so, knowing an average win rate tells you very little about the probability between two teams.  for example, if every game, between any two teams, is decided by the toss of a fair coin then you'll get (nearly) 50% win rates for every team...but in the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors you also get 50% for every team.  So...you need more assumptions to get a good answer.

Comment: I presume there are no draws ?

Comment: There are no draws, overtime would always decide a map winner if it comes to that.

Comment: Also lulu, I can clear that up a bit. It doesn't matter what each teams winrate is, as much as I just wanted to present a scenario where a team was statistically favored going into the scenario. From that point forward I really just wanted to learn how less likely an upset was when the format has a larger sample size. Obviously if both teams are equal then the odds don't change when you go from best of 1 game to best of 3 instead. So I guess I don't how to set the odds in this question to get the answer I'm looking for, maybe 60/40 for team A